# Create the width_bucket function from Oracle SQL in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm looking to replicate the `width_bucket` function that is available in Oracle with a new function in BigQuery. The function creates equiwidth buckets based on the number you specify between a min and max value. For example, `width_bucket(user_count, 0, 35, 10)` would create 10 equal buckets like 0 - 3.5, 3.5 - 7, etc and tell you which bucket `user_count` falls in. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Oracle doc - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions214.htm

Here's what I have and I believe this works, but I want to get it so I don't have to reference a table if possible to generate the row numbers.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION functions.widthBucket(
  value NUMERIC,
  minValue NUMERIC,
  maxValue NUMERIC,
  buckets INT64)
AS ((
  SELECT resultBucket 
  FROM (
      SELECT CASE 
               WHEN value >= (minValue * bucketNumber) + ((maxValue/buckets) * (bucketNumber - 1))
                AND value < (maxValue/buckets) * bucketNumber 
               THEN bucketNumber
               WHEN value = maxValue and bucketNumber = buckets 
               THEN bucketNumber
             ELSE -1 
             END as resultBucket
      FROM (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY '') as bucketNumber
            FROM project.dateTable
           ) x
      WHERE bucketNumber <= buckets) x
  WHERE resultBucket != -1
  ));
```

Comment: can you provide example of how you plan to use such UDF - with some dummy data for testing :o) asking because i don't seems to understand what that table is doing inside the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Try below - I think it does exactly what you asked

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION widthBucket(
  value NUMERIC, 
  minValue NUMERIC, 
  maxValue NUMERIC, 
  buckets NUMERIC
) AS (
  RANGE_BUCKET(value, GENERATE_ARRAY(minValue, maxValue, (maxValue - minValue)/buckets))
);
```

The use is as simple as in your question
For example, `widthBucket(user_count, 0, 35, 10)`

To address edge case when value equal to the maxValue - use below variation of above

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION widthBucket(
  value NUMERIC, 
  minValue NUMERIC, 
  maxValue NUMERIC, 
  buckets NUMERIC
) AS ((
  SELECT IF(bucket > buckets, buckets, bucket)
  FROM (
    SELECT RANGE_BUCKET(value, GENERATE_ARRAY(minValue, maxValue, (maxValue - minValue)/buckets)) bucket
  )
));
```

Comment: Ah yes, that works pretty well and much cleaner. One problem though, if you set the value equal to the maxValue, the result is buckets + 1. Thoughts?

Comment: sure. this behavior makes sense as it is how RANGE_BUCKET works. So see update in the answer to handle this scenario